# Tabulator JS: After loading data column not rendering

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, tabulator

after i loading the data via ajax in [tabulatorJS](http://tabulator.info/), the column header titles changed to data value name.
The ajax response is a java object, which has the same attribute names as the field name in tabulator columns.
The response you can see at bottom of this article.
[Data found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBaDb.png)

If no data found the table was rendered correctly.
[No data found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ArUi.png)

Have you any idea?

```
table = new Tabulator("#table-div", {
    ajaxURL: '/loadDataObject.do',
    ajaxConfig: 'GET',
    ajaxParams: {name: $('#name').val()},
    // data: dataObject,
    responsiveLayout: true,
    keybindings: true,
    locale: true,
    langs: {
        "de-de": {
        }
    },
    movableColumns: true,
    movableRows: true,
    resizableRows: false,
    headerSort: false,
    autoColumns: true,
    autoResize: true,
    layout: 'fitColumns',
    placeholder: $.i18n.prop('table.no_data_found'),
    columns: [
        {rowHandle:true, formatter:"handle", headerSort:false, frozen:true, width:30, minWidth:30, cssClass: 'disabled'},
        {title: $.i18n.prop('table.pos_number'), field: 'posNumber', editor: 'input', width: 40},
        {title: $.i18n.prop('table.symbol'), field: 'classSymbol', width: 45, cssClass: 'disabled item-symbol'},
        {title: $.i18n.prop('table.item_work_operation_number'), field: 'itemNumber', editor: 'input', width: 70, cssClass: 'item-number text-uppercase'},
        {title: $.i18n.prop('table.item_work_operation_name'), field: 'itemName', width: 300, cssClass: 'disabled item-name'},
        {title: $.i18n.prop('table.item_length'), field: 'itemLength', width: 70, cssClass: 'disabled item-length'},
        {title: $.i18n.prop('table.item_width'), field: 'itemWidth', width: 70, cssClass: 'disabled item-width'},
        {title: $.i18n.prop('table.item_height'), field: 'itemHeight', width: 70, cssClass: 'disabled item-height'},
        {title: $.i18n.prop('table.warehouse_storage_unit'), field: 'warehouseStorageUnit', width: 70, cssClass: 'disabled warehouse-storage-unit'},
        {title: $.i18n.prop('table.position_text'), field: 'positionText', editor: 'input', width: 200}]);
```

AJAX-Response

```
[
       {
          "posNumber":"1",
          "classSymbol":"fa-shopping-cart",
          "itemNumber":"V000092",
          "itemName":"Test asd asd a         ",
          "itemLength":1234000.34,
          "itemWidth":0.0,
          "itemHeight":0.0,
          "warehouseStorageUnit":"mm",
          "positionText":"jsdfakjfjöq",
          "quantity":12.0,
          "fCode":"ML",
          "benefit":12.0,
          "cutLength":0.0,
          "cutWidth":0.0,
          "cutHeight":0.0,
          "edge":"H",
          "edgeProperty":"",
          "provisionType":""
       }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have ***autoColumns*** enabled.

With auto columns enabled it will automatically create the tables columns based on the data returened.

If you want to define the columns first the you should simply not define the ***autoColumns*** option in your table setup